# JQuery: Execute call when .load() has finished inserting new html?

Tags: jquery

I have a function that I call to load html returned from a php file into a div. Once the html is placed in the div I want it to call a jquery function for colorbox that shows the div. The problem I have is that the call back is executed before the html is actually placed into the div. Is there a way to get jquery to run a function when the html has actually been placed fully into the div as opposed to when it just finishes executing the php?

The function looks like this...

```
function viewDetails(vinNum){
    $('#detailsContainer').load('/actions/myfile.php?var='+myVar,function(){
        $(".example3").colorbox({transition:"elastic", speed:"100", inline:true, href:"#hiddenModalContentbox"});
    });
}
```

The problem is that the callback is called before it actually finishes putting the html into the div. Could this be caused by the php putting out some html while it's waiting for mysql to give it the data it needs? If so, should I retrieve all the data and echo out all the html at once?

---

EDIT:
this is what I've tried now, with the same result. I also added a javascript alert to the php file that is being loaded. The alert is called AFTER the colorbox is called by the callback.

```
function viewDetails(myVar) {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/actions/myfile.php', 
        data: 'var=' + myVar,
        success: function(html) {
            $('#detailsContainer').html(html);
        },
        complete: function(){
            $(".example3").colorbox({transition:"elastic", speed:"100", inline:true, href:"#hiddenModalContentbox"});
        }
    });
}
```

---

EDIT FINAL: I discovered that the colorbox was being called improperly from the beginning. I inherited some of the code from someone else, and I thought it was set up right. All I had to do was remove the (".example3") class call and it works just fine. That class call attaches the method to any links with that class thus calling it BEFORE the callback finishes. All the callback does is reassign the colorbox method to the items with that class again. All my ramblings probably make things clear as mud, but thanks for the input everyone. Here's the final working call...

```
$('#detailsContainer').load('/actions/myfile.php?var='+myVar,function(){
        $.colorbox({transition:"elastic", speed:"100", inline:true, href:"#hiddenModalContentbox"});                                                                   
    });
```

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Comment: Your statement is wrong, the callback occurs when the html is actually put in the target element, see http://jsfiddle.net/3ZAQB/1/ The technology behind the loaded content doesn't matter AT ALL. jQuery doesn't care if it's PHP and if there's any MySQL connection in the script. All it sees is an URL delivering HTML. And if some HTML is delivered, that means PHP has finished generating it. It could take 10sec to deliver, the callback will fire after these 10sec (+ the few microseconds it takes to append it).

Comment: sdology - I understand document ready. The problem is I'm not loading a whole page, I'm loading a chunk of html from a php. There's no application of document ready for that purpose to my knowledge.

Comment: the ready event has indeed nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I think I see the problem now. I inherited some of this code from someone else, and I had assumed that it was implemented properly. Now I see that the colorbox call was attached improperly from the beginning. It looks like I have to go back and edit the colorbox source to make it work with  my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to actually use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  This will open you up to methods like ajaxStart, ajaxStop, complete, error, success, etc.  Using .load() pulls $.ajax() anyway so you might as well give yourself all the goodies that come along with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop down to `$.get` or `$.ajax` and insert the HTML yourself, thus verifying it has occurred, before calling colorbox.

```
function viewDetails(vinNum) {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/actions/myfile.php', 
        data: { var: myVar },
        success: function(html) {
            $('#detailsContainer').html(html);
            $('.example3').colorbox ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Which is exactly what load() does ;-) I think the problem lies in colorbox, not in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought it's unlikely that the php will echo some HTML before it's got the data, but it also rather depends on where you are echoing the data in the script.

Having said that I have also found .load() to be problematic, but I didn't spend enough time trying to find out why. My problem was slightly different in that I wanted to create elements dynamically on the page.

Hang on a minute damn you guys are fast.... See T Stone's answer

Answer (score 0):

No, the callback is executing after the content is actually loaded but the plugin you're trying to use (colorbox) probably doesn't work if the elements are dynamically loaded.

The best way to verify this is to try to alert something coming from the loaded part, like:

```
console.log($('.example3').html());
```

If it shows the element content, then the content is loaded and accessible through the DOM when the callback is fired and the only culprit is colorbox.

To demonstrate the callback of `load()` indeed fires after the loaded content is actually appended to the DOM, here is a small demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ZAQB/1/

Comment: I put an alert in the php file that I'm calling. The callback is triggered before i get the alert.